# SQL: How can I check if two values in column A belong to the same group defined in column B?

Tags: sql, postgresql

### This is my db "users":

```
user    group   show_groupmembers
----------------------------------
Bob     Alpha   Y
Peter   Alpha   N
Peter   Beta    Y
Chris   Beta    Y
```

If show_groupmembers is "Y", the user can see the all other members of his group.
(So Bob for example can see all "Alpha"-Group users)

If show_groupmembers is "N", the user can't see any members of his group 
(So Peter for example can't see any "Alpha"-Group users)

### And here is what I wanna do:

I have a current_user, Peter and want to check if Peter can see Bob.
So it must be checked that

1. there are in the same group and
2. the flag  "show_groupmembers" of the urrent_user (Peter) is 'Y'.

If this check fails (like in my example), the "EXIST SELECT 1" should
return nothing of course, else it should return something.

I've seen solutions that work, but only if the current_user is only member of one group. As soon as he is more groups, the check above seems not to work.

Any Ideas how to perform this? I am totally stuck with that.

Comment: See update and fiddle

Comment: Edit your sample data to show users in multiple groups. Make sure the rest of your question lines up.

Comment: Updated my answer to include searching in a specific group and searching for links between two people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned using an exist:

```
select u1.user, u1.group, u1.show_groupmembers
from users u1
where exists ( select 1
              from users u2
              where u2.user = 'Peter'
              and u2.show_groupmembers = 'Y'
              and u1.group = u2.group )
```

Some edits:

If you want the list of users that Peter can see in a certain group:

```
select u1.user, u1.group, u1.show_groupmembers
from users u1
where u1.group = 'Alpha'
and exists ( select 1
              from users u2
              where u2.user = 'Peter'
              and u2.show_groupmembers = 'Y'
              and u1.group = u2.group )
```

If you want to check whether Peter can see Bob:

```
select u1.user, u1.group, u1.show_groupmembers
from users u1
where u1.user = 'Bob'
and exists ( select 1
              from users u2
              where u2.user = 'Peter'
              and u2.show_groupmembers = 'Y'
              and u1.group = u2.group )
```

Comment: you have an sp `exits` should be `exists`

Answer (score 0):

```
select u1.user, u1.group, u1.show_groupmembers
from users u1
join (select user, group, show_groupmembers 
        from users where user = 'Joe' and show_groupmembers = 'Y'
) u2
on u1.group = u2.group;
```

See this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/22ff1/7

Comment: sorry that doesn't work. Just returns me a list of all users, their groups where show_groupmembers is true.

Comment: @Sam I actually added that in the inner select. I misunderstood OP's intentions.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Kevin: doesn't work. When I search for Joe in your fiddle example, he returns Bob and Jane. They are in his group, but since Joes flag is on "N" he is not allowed to see him and the select should return empty list

Comment: @fox1986 are we looking at the same fiddle? I just ran the same test and it worked.  Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/22ff1/7

Comment: @Kevin: Ok it does work when Joe is member of only one group. But as soon as he is member of Alpha AND Beta for example, the check if he is allowed to see Bob will fail. Instead of an empty list, i will get a list of all Beta Groupmembers he can see.

Comment: @fox1986 Didn't see you slip the multiple groups in there

Answer (score 0):

Returns 1 Peter can see Bob; otherwise, returns 0.

```
with can_u1 as (
  select * from table1 where "user" = 'Peter'
),
see_u2 as (
  select * from table1 where "user" = 'Bob'
)
select count(*)
from can_u1
inner join see_u2 on can_u1."group" = see_u2."group"
and can_u1.show_groupmembers = 'Y'
where can_u1."group" = 'Alpha'
```

I think maintenance is easier for this particular kind of query if you name both users. Returning a count guarantees that information can't leak to the users, although it's not clear whether this is an issue for you.

Both "user" and "group" are reserved words in PostgreSQL. Use more descriptive column names.

Comment: Doesn't help either since I don't know the group. I have only a current_user and a user from the db to compare.

Comment: @fox1986 Just drop the where can_u1."group" = 'Alpha' in the query. If the return is 0, Peter cannot see Bob. If the return > 0, then there is at least one group where Peter can see Bob.

Comment: @Sam: You can't do without the WHERE clause. The users can be in multiple groups. You have to make sure you're checking in the particular group in question, since their visibility might be different in each group.

Comment: Fox1986 said he did not know the group though, so the best you can do is check if there is an 'is there any group where Peter can see Bob' check for visibility. Dropping the WHERE gives you the number of groups where Peter can see Bob. Comparing the return to '0 or 1' no longer gives you any useful information (since 2, 3,... are also valid returns), but you can use '0 or larger than 0'.

Comment: @fox1986: *"I don't know the group"* I'm not sure what you think your table means, then, but "I don't know the group" seems to be a significant defect in design. Why? Peter and Bob might be members of one group that says Peter *can* see Bob, and another group that says Peter *can't* see Bob. Think long and hard before you implement something that has semantics like this.